# Kendo validation in table cell show on top (z-index)

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

my issue is that the validation message of kendo within a grid (inside a td) is hidden inside the grid. Is there anyway I can show it on top of everything? I tried with position:relative, z-index etc. but nothing worked. 
Screenshot of issue:[image]

and plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/Wyf24V/preview

Add a few entries, then add an empty string and save. the validation message will be hidden inside grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record I solved it using the following code, every time a row is updated:

```
var gridContent = grid.find('.k-grid-content');
if (gridContent.find('.k-widget.k-tooltip.k-tooltip-validation.k-invalid-msg').length > 0) {
        gridContent.css("overflow", "visible");
    } else {
        gridContent.css("overflow", "auto");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try position:fixed; worked when I tried on your plunker

Comment: Position fixed doesn't match here, it could have many errors 1 of them being that when you scroll the grid the validation message remains there.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since this answered was asked, but I had the same issue and the answers I found didn't work for me. I found a pretty simple solution that I thought I would share.  If you are using an angularjs custom editor you can do the following:

```
//columns property inside kendo options object
columns: [
    { field: "Policy", title: "Policy", editor: createDropDownEditor },
    //other column definitions here...
]

//schema property inside kendo options object
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "Id",  //whatever your unique id is per row
        fields: {
            Policy: {
                validation: {
                    required: true,
                    policyValidation: function (input) {
                        return input.val() !== "-- Select --";
                    }
                }
            },
            //other fields
        }
    }
}

//outside of kendo options object define the createTextEditor function

function createDropDownEditor (container, options){
    //using ES6 backticks, but you can use string concatination instead
    $(` <select kendo-drop-down-list
            name="${options.field}"
            k-options="vm.getDropDownListOptions()"></select>`)
            .appendTo(container);
        /*
        This line makes the validation message show up even though it
        extends to outside the td
        */
        container.css("overflow", "visible");
        /*
        This line makes the content show up even if it extends
        outside of the body of the kendo grid.
        The downside to this is that the scroll bar on the right
        disappears when entering the field with this editor
        which makes the columns not line up.  If you can find a way to
        fix that issue it would be the preferred solution IMO
        */
        container.closest(".k-grid-content").css("overflow", "visible");

}

//inside your controller
getDropDownListOptions(){
    return {
        dataSource: ["option1", "option2", "option3"],
        optionLabel: "-- Select --"
    }
}
```

another thing you can do is add a class to the kendo grid and just add some padding to always allow enough room underneath your rows for the validation message.

```
.my-custom .k-grid-content {
    padding-bottom: 32px;
}
```

This is actually what worked best for my needs, but I would still prefer to use:

```
container.closest(".k-grid-content").css("overflow", "visible");
```

from above if it didn't mess up the grids columns.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Add this css according to the documentation https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#scrolling


`#GridID .k-grid-header { padding: 0 !important; }`

`#GridID .k-grid-content { overflow-y: visible; }`